# Multi-Container ASP.NET Core App with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

How can I create a Multi-Container ASP.NET Core App with Docker Compose ?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a tutorial website, its main purpose is to help with issues and ask community helpful questions. see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292175/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new asp.net core web api project
2. Create new asp.net core web application project
3. Right click web api project -> Add -> Add Container Orchestrator Support -> Docker Compose -> Ok  ->Target OS -> Linux -> Ok
4. Right click web application project -> Add -> Add Container Orchestrator Support -> Docker Compose -> Ok  ->Target OS -> Linux -> Ok
5. Finaly you will have a new project as docker-compose, and it will be contains docker-compose.yml

[image]

6. docker-compose.yml must be like this, but we will develop this file

   ```
    version: '3.4'

    services:
      api:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Api/Dockerfile

      webapp:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapp
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: WebApp/Dockerfile
   ```
7. Open cmd and run this code for ssl

   > dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p mypass123
8. You will have aspnetapp.pfx file in C:\users.....\https , copy and paste this file to each asp.net core project https folder
9. And develope docker-compose.yml as below

   ```
    version: '3.4'

    services:
      api:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Api/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "9000:443"
          - "9001:80"
        environment:
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
          - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
          - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=9000
          - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypass123
          - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
        volumes:
            - ./Api/https/aspnetapp.pfx:/https/aspnetapp.pfx:ro 

      webapp:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapp
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: WebApp/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "9002:443"
          - "9003:80"
        environment:
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
          - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
          - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=9000
          - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypass123
          - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
        volumes:
            - ./WebApp/https/aspnetapp.pfx:/https/aspnetapp.pfx:ro
   ```
10. Thats it, you can run docker-compose file

> docker-compose up

[image]